# What are the purpose of Targets in the .Net Core xUnit Test-Runner Output, and how do I use them?

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I'm building a Web API using .Net Core. I'm building and running my unit tests as I go. When I run my tests, I get something like this:

```
The-Monarch:MyAwesomeService.Tests homr$ dotnet test
Project MyAwesomeService (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
Project MyAwesomeService.Tests (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because inputs were modified
Compiling MyAwesomeService.Tests for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:01.2618204


xUnit.net .NET CLI test runner (64-bit osx.10.11-x64)
  Discovering: MyAwesomeService.Tests
  Discovered:  MyAwesomeService.Tests
  Starting:    MyAwesomeService.Tests
  Finished:    MyAwesomeService.Tests
=== TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
   MyAwesomeService.Tests  Total: 20, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 3.522s
SUMMARY: Total: 1 targets, Passed: 1, Failed: 0.
The-Monarch:MyAwesomeService.Tests homr$
```

I'm curious about the line that says `SUMMARY: Total: 1 targets, Passed: 1, Failed: 0.`.  So far, I've never seen a total higher than "1" here. How do you get more than one "Test Target" in a single output, and what's the purpose?

Comment: You probably never will: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/

Comment: @9swampy I don't see what you're referring to in that post.

Comment: sorry, fair comment; perhaps a little obtuse but I was alluding to the presumption that targeting multiple project.json was undoubtedly on the roadmapwhen they added the summary, but given they've announced "it would be easier to move .NET Core projects to .csproj/MSBuild so all .NET projects use the same tooling and build system" it will never happen

Comment: Ah. So, you're saying "targets" refer to projects.